# Uploading form in html issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

Having form code to upload file in php,see code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="ok.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="ghf" name="str"><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Check image:

[image]

But of we open this form in different browsers it saying as Browse in firefox and Choose file in Chrome(refer to image,on top is chrome,second is firefox)
Question is i want to change name of this Choose file or Browse,is it possible?If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearance of file type field is different with different browsers.

Default behavior of chrome does not display textbox and button for the file type fields.

You can refer this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <img src="/images/uploadButton.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" />
    <input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" style="display:none" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
<!--Load jQuery from Google Libraries-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Using jQuery
    $("#upfile1").click(function () {
        $("#file1").trigger('click');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input[type=file]` is a native browser object and can't be changed within.

What you can try and do is create a custom wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

these are by Default button styles of submit button.

You can edit it either by adding this:

Value attribute is used to define names of button.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp